# Ruby Parse PDF file having text and images

Tags: ruby, pdf

I have a pdf file having both **text** and **images** contents. I need to parse it. Is there any ruby gem can be useful? I have tried [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) ruby gem but didn't parse images :(

One alternative solution is to extract the pdf to html and then parse the html contents. Is there any open source pdf2html convertor can work with **both** text and images?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse'? Do you want to extract data? render a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdf-reader can extract images, however there isn't a nice helper like PDF::Reader::Page#text() so it's pretty manual.

Checkout the extract_images.rd example @ [1].

[1] https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/blob/master/examples/extract_images.rb

Comment: when I try to run extractor = ExtractImages::Extractor.new, it gives error "input must be an IO-like object or a filename"